# Passing Html string to div innerhtml and its causing errors

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm running into an error when I try put this is in a textbox like this,

```
tbGameTitle.Text = "<iframe id = 'ForIframe' src='http://e.gamesalad.com/play/117208' allowTransparency='true' scrolling='no'></iframe>";
```

when I click on my button

```
myThing.InnerHtml = tbGameTitle.Text;
```

it throws this error

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (tbGameTitle="<iframe id = 'ForIfr...").
```

If I have this load on the pageload event then its fine. But as soon as I enter this in the textbox and click on my button, it throws that error. I had it working in another project from way back and it never threw this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net form content is checked for dangerous content when it is submitted (things like HTML and javascript are flagged as being potentially dangerous and are rejected). There are a few ways of allowing this content to be submitted, HTML encoding your text before it is send to the server or disabling request validation using a tag in the top of your page (potentially unsafe!):

```
<@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

More information on request validation can be found at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This worked, the only thing I am hoping is that when I add requiredfieldvalidation that it cause any conflicts

Comment: Remember to manually check the passed data server side for malicious input if you have turned request validation off!

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape characters like "<".
Read a little about: [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

This [post](http://codingstill.com/2013/01/avoiding-the-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected/) must be helpful.

---

the main code you want from that page is:

```
// The event to escape the data and store in our HiddenField
jQuery('.allow_html textarea').blur(function () {
    jQuery(jQuery(this).parent()).find('input[type="hidden"]').val(escape(jQuery(this).val()));
});

// The code to unescape the code and set it in our textbox
jQuery('.allow_html textarea').each(function(idx, item) {
    var value = jQuery(jQuery(item).parent()).find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
    jQuery(item).val(unescape(value));
});
```

that will escape HTML code in the input.

and, at the server side you need to unescape it:

```
// encode the data
HtmlCodeHiddenField.Value = Uri.EscapeDataString(EscapedHtml);
// decode the data
string myHtml = Uri.UnescapeDataString(HtmlCodeHiddenField.Value);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on your answer?  Posting mostly link-only answers typically wind up being deleted.